# How to convert $10^n$ to scientific notation where $n \in \Bbb Q$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, scientific-notation

> How to convert $10^n$  to scientific notation where $n \in \Bbb Q$?

For simplicity take the example $10^{7.44}$.

I know how to convert scientific notations to the power of $10$.

Like If we want to convert $3 \times 10^{-5}$ in power of $10$.

We can take $\log _{10}$ both sides of the equation $10^{n}=3 \times 10^{-5}$ and get the results .

So can we also do like this in reverse order to get the answer of my question?

Comment: $10^n=10^{\{n\}}10^{\lfloor n\rfloor}$ where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the largest integer smaller than or equal to $x$, e.g. $10^{7.44}=10^{0.44}\times10^7$. Or were you asking about how to calculate (say) $10^{0.44}$?

Comment: @Kyky  Of course yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $10^{7.44}=10^{0.44} \times 10^7$, which is in scientific notation because $1\le10^{0.44}<10$ and $10^7$ is an integer power of $10$. However, in this context it would be more common to write $10^{0.44}$ as a decimal, and so we would write
$$
10^{7.44}=2.75 \times10^7
$$
where $10^{0.44}$ has been given to $3$ significant figures. I don't think there is a feasible way of computing $10^{0.44}$ without a calculator, although you can reason that
$$
2=8^{0.333}<10^{0.44}<16^{0.5}=4
$$
which gives you a *very* rough approximation.